# Using Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP as a child

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm trying to use timestamp as a child but couldn't get it work,

```
var ref = new Firebase(url);
var currentRef = ref.child('current');

currentRef.transaction(function(currentValue) {
  if (currentValue == null) {
    return;
  } else {
    return Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
  }
}, function(err, committed, snapshot) {


  var time = snapshot.val();


  // ### time returns Object {.sv: "timestamp"} 
  console.log(time);

  ref.child(time); // ### fails here because time is not a proper number
});
```

I've tried to listen to `currentRef` as well but with no luck

```
currentRef.on('value', function(data) {

  // ### data.val() still returns Object {.sv: "timestamp"}
  console.log(data.val());
});
```

It only works if I listen on `currentRef` with a longer timeout (> 5 seconds) - after the data is fully written in the server.

Is it possible to do this with client-only code?

Comment: [Engineer at Firebase] If the data is being properly written to the server, but not respected on your local client, then that sounds like a bug. I'll look into it and follow-up here. Also, please let me know if you're also experiencing this problem using `.set(...)` or `.push(...)`.

Comment: Thanks! It works fine with `.set`. I haven't got a chance to try it with `.push` though

Comment: it works fine on `.push` too. This might be transaction bug

Comment: Thanks for filing this issue. A bugfix will be released next Monday or Tuesday. Thanks!